# Android: EditText not appearing when setting styles programmatically

Tags: android, styles, android-edittext, tablelayout

I need to create UI controls programmatically and my EditText is not appearing on the screen.

This is a sort of skeleton xml in which I will add table rows programmatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout">

        <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/myTable" >

        </TableLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is the java code in my Activity,

```
TableLayout mainTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTable);
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("Text1");
row.addView(textView);

EditText editText = new EditText(this, null, R.style.editTextStyle);
row.addView(editText);

mainTable.addView(row);
```

My editTextStyle is the following,

```
<style name="editTextStyle">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">7dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">27sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">150dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
</style>
```

The textView is appearing normally, but the editText isn't. Any ideas please?

Comment: You have not added lauoyt/ size to your textView

Comment: @ChintanRaghwani I added the layout_width and layout_height in my style.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android 4.0.3 then in your LinearLayout remove the

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

or otherwise you can set any background color for edittext ie.

in you style add item as

```
<item name="android:background">your required color </item>
```

Then you can able to see the edittext .

You can also do like the following in your activity

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setBackgroundColor(R.color.BLUE);
editText.setTextColor(R.color.BLACK);
row.addView(editText);
```

in color.xml

```
<resources>
<color name="Black">#000000</color>
<color name="Blue">#FF006767</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I am using Android 4.0.3, but I tried both your suggestions and unfortunately editText still isn't appearing.

Comment: Yes, it would work if I use the EditText constructor that takes a context only. Put I have a lot of styles for all my different UI components and I want to add the style programmatically. Thats why I used the constructor that takes a style as third parameter.